# In S3, can we turn on versioning and encryption at object level instead of bucket level?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In S3, can we turn on versioning and encryption at bucket level.

Any objects that existed prior to versioning or encryption turned on will not have versioning (version id is null) and encryption respectively. You can then go to these preexisting objects and turn on encryption for that object. Similarly you can add new verison of object and it will have new version id.

Instead of configuring these settings at the bucket level, can we turn on versioning and encryption at object level instead of bucket level?

Answer (score 0):

Versioning is a bucket level feature, if you want to manage older versioning based on prefixes for example you can either automate using [EventBridge](https://aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/) to have a Lambda delete these or add a [lifecycle rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html) for prefixes to delete older versions.

Regarding encryption, these settings on the bucket are actually to apply [default application of encryption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/bucket-encryption.html) against objects. If you only want a specific object to be encrypted you can [specify the encryption method](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingServerSideEncryption.html) during your ut object request.

Answer (score 0):

Versioning is enabled on S3 buckets. You can't enable it object by object.

You can [enable default server-side encryption](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/bucket-encryption.html) for all new objects via S3 bucket policy. That doesn't encrypt older objects.

You can request server-side encryption on an object-by-object basis at the time of upload or afterwards. You can always encrypt client-side before uploading, of course.

You can also [prevent the upload of unencrypted objects](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/security/how-to-prevent-uploads-of-unencrypted-objects-to-amazon-s3/).